# Django cannot get values from ManyToMany field

Tags: python-3.x, django

I have written a blog application and I have a Post model. When a new Post is created the system sends a link for the new post to a Telegram group.

The Post has a `telegram_chat` `ManyToMany` field. When the Post is saved, the `post_save` signal handler sends the link. However, there are no `chat_id` values for the `ManyToMany` queryset `post.telegram_chats`.

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    """Post Model"""
    hash = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField("Title", max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tags = TaggableManager()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='post_images/', blank=True, null=True)
    content = RichTextUploadingField()
    telegram_chats = models.ManyToManyField('TelegramChat', related_name='posts', blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}"
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("main:post_detail", args=[self.slug])
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if str(self.hash) not in self.slug:
            self.slug = f"{self.slug}-{self.hash}" 
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    
@receiver(post_save, sender=Post)
def send_telegram_message(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    bot_token = 'YOUR_TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN'
        
    # Check if the post has associated chat IDs
    if instance.telegram_chats.exists():
        chat_ids = instance.telegram_chats.values_list('chat_id', flat=True)
    
    bot = Bot(token=bot_token)
    
    # You may customize the message format as needed
    message = f"New post: {instance.title}\n\n{instance.content}\n\nLink: https://yourdomain.com/path-to-post/{instance.id}/"
    
    if instance.image:
        image_path = instance.image.path
        for chat_id in chat_ids:
            bot.send_photo(chat_id=chat_id, photo=InputFile(image_path), caption=message)
    else:
        for chat_id in chat_ids:
            bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=message)
```

Comment: At the time of the creation, the m2m is *always* empty: it first has to create the `Post` before it can populate the m2m, so the signal is always too early, it is one of the (many) problems with signals: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/signals.html

Comment: What can help me to solve my problem?

Comment: Trigger the logic in the view, not through signals.

Comment: Good question, I had a similar problem! I think @willeM_VanOnsem is right on his comment.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of the creation, the m2m is always empty: it first has to create the Post before it can populate the m2m, so the signal is always too early, it is one of the (many) problems with signals. In fact, it turns of signals are often an [*antipattern* <sup>[Django-antipatterns]</sup>](https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/signals.html). Indeed, it is not a very robust mechanism, that can easily get codeflow stuck in an infinite loop, or run too early (or too late).

It might be better to just encapsulate the logic into a function, like you already did:

```
def send_telegram_message(instance):
    bot_token = 'YOUR_TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN'

    if instance.telegram_chats.exists():
        chat_ids = instance.telegram_chats.values_list('chat_id', flat=True)

    bot = Bot(token=bot_token)
    message = f"New post: {instance.title}\n\n{instance.content}\n\nLink: https://yourdomain.com/path-to-post/{instance.id}/"

    if instance.image:
        image_path = instance.image.path
        for chat_id in chat_ids:
            bot.send_photo(
                chat_id=chat_id, photo=InputFile(image_path), caption=message
            )
    else:
        for chat_id in chat_ids:
            bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=message)
```

and then run this in the view *after* you created/updated the object:

```
def my_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            item = form.save()
            send_telegram_message(item)
            return redirect('name-of-some-view')
    else:
        form = MyForm()
    return render(request, 'name-of-some-template.html', {'form': form})
```